# SQL request to change all titles

Tags: mysql

I need to add one word, for example `Nike` to all titles.
I have a part of solution

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_title = 
WHERE post_type = 'product';
```

But thing I don't understand is **how to get title, and add to each title word `Nike` with space before**.

Example

```
Men T shirt
```

I need

```
Men T shirt Nike
```

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_title = replace(post_title," Nike","")
WHERE post_type = 'product';
```

Is it right?

I think, that must work

```
SET post_title = replace(post_title,"Some title","Some title + Nike")
```

But how get Some title? There are to many posts with different titles?

Comment: Give an example of an existing title and the result you want to achieve

Comment: I add example. I try to made like Jens say, but it breaks my base. All i found - is replace function but how to get each title and + word to it?

Answer (score 1):

Found workable solution

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = CONCAT( post_title,  ' Nike' ) WHERE post_type =  'product';
```

- **REPLACE()** -Replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with
  another string value.
- **CONCAT()** -function is used to concatenate 2 or more strings together
  and forms a single string.